# Why type cast to id will get rid of this error message "Collection element of type 'CGColorRef' (aka 'struct CGColor *') is not an Objective-C object"

Tags: objective-c, struct, casting

Here is the code in question

```
UIColor *colorOne = [UIColor colorWithRed:(120/255.0) green:(135/255.0) blue:(150/255.0) alpha:1.0];
UIColor *colorTwo = [UIColor colorWithRed:(57/255.0)  green:(79/255.0)  blue:(96/255.0)  alpha:1.0];


CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;

gradient.colors = @[ [colorOne CGColor], [colorTwo CGColor] ];  // ERROR
```

The last line will yield this error message:

```
MyController.m:31:26: Collection element of type 'CGColorRef' 
    (aka 'struct CGColor *') is not an Objective-C object
```

However, if I change the line to

```
gradient.colors = @[ (id)[colorOne CGColor], (id) [colorTwo CGColor] ];
```

It silences the compiler.

Why casting a struct type to `id` works? Is it because we trick the compiler to believe that a `struct` type has become a class without method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is documented in the ["Transitioning to ARC Release Notes"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> The compiler understands Objective-C methods that return Core
>   Foundation types follow the historical Cocoa naming conventions (see
>   [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i)). For example, the
>   compiler knows that, in iOS, the CGColor returned by the CGColor
>   method of UIColor is not owned. You must still use an appropriate type
>   cast, as illustrated by this example:
>
> ```
> NSMutableArray *colors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:(id)[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
> [colors addObject:(id)[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
> ```